# MySQLAdmin Procedures Running code Twice

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQLAdmin. I have a procedure that inserts a new row into a table, but instead of adding it once, it does it twice. Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_game(IN game_name VARCHAR(50), IN game_price DOUBLE) 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO games (id, name, price) VALUES (NULL, game_name, game_price);
  SELECT * FROM games;
END

SELECT * FROM games;

| id | name     | price |
|----|----------|-------|
|  1 | chess    | 12.95 |
|  2 | life!    | 10.55 |
|  3 | checkers | 10.55 |

CALL add_game('jacks', 3.69);

| id | name     | price |
|----|----------|-------|
|  1 | chess    | 12.95 |
|  2 | life!    | 10.55 |
|  3 | checkers | 10.55 |
|  4 | jacks    |  3.69 |
|  5 | jacks    |  3.69 |
```

Why would it do this?

UPDATE:

When I change the name column to be unique, I get an error message saying:

```
Error
SQL query:


CALL add_game('chess', 5.98)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'chess' for key 'name'
```

Comment: What calls this procedure? You wanna check there

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh I am calling it from the sql console in MySQLAdmin.

Comment: Are there any `INSERT` triggers on the table which could be duplicating the record when it's inserted?

Comment: Also, you've tagged this as [`sql-server`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) but seem to be talking about MySQL - which is it?